# Mimi knows she has HIV but still wants to have sex with Roger?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, rent

In *Rent*, Mimi (Rosario Dawson) knows that she is HIV positive and still wants to have an affair with Roger. While he declines her offers because he knows that he is positive too and so he doesn't want to infect her, she doesn't seem to care about this, but it is clear that she doesn't know that he's positive too.

Is she such a bad person? And why does Roger not complain about her behaviour?

Comment: I agree that Mimi is still getting around sexually while Roger avoids it at all costs. What about Benny? Is he HIV positive or just cautious as he cheats on his wife with Mimi?

Answer (score 3):

Ok a couple of things spring to mind.

1. Mimi is a drug addict, as revealed in the song 'light my candle'. It could be said that a drug addict would not have full concideration to the consequences of her actions.

   http://www.metrolyrics.com/light-my-candle-lyrics-rent.html
2. Roger recognises something in her that reminds him of his previous partner, and also somethings in her life that he can relate to.

However, there is one thing that your question does miss. If they were going to have sex why wouldn't they use condoms, roger is well aware of his status, and is in control of his HIV as seen by the segment where everyone pauses for medication. Even if you assume Mimi is not able to make that decision - Which I don't, Roger is.

You ask if Mimi is a bad person.  No, she is lonely, looking for love or partnership, a connection, as is Roger.   We all make mistakes and bad decisions when looking for love, or seeking that someone special.

Comment: I see your point, but maybe my question is, why does Roger have problems in having sex with Mimi while she doesn't care at all? Why don't they tackle the problem at least later on?

Comment: I think this is one of those things where you have to assume that something took place off screen, unless it's going to be key to the plot we are unlikely to see it.  Or as I was once told - it's a musical they don't have to make sense.